# Mac OS X Lion has no /Developer/usr folder

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, compiler-construction, osx-lion

I have been fiddling around trying to get Eclipse for C++ working on Mac OS X Lion.

I have downloaded Xcode 4.3, so there should be a /Developer/usr folder with gcc, g++, make and other compiler commands. However, while I have a /Developer folder, I do not have a /Developer/usr folder anywhere.

Where can I get this from? I think it may have disappeared when I attempted to symlink the contents of /Developer/usr/bin to the default /usr/bin for Eclipse to use. Not sure if this can even happen.

This has driven me crazy for about a week now!

Comment: Did you read the release notes for Xcode 4.3?

Answer (score 13):

`/Developer` was moved to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` in Xcode 4.3.

Comment: I found it there and added it to the C++ build environment variable PATH... now i get this error:**** Build of configuration Debug for project asking ****

make all 
make: echo: No such file or directory
make: *** [src/asking.o] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****........ as well as cout, con and std not being recognized. There is an error about #include <iostream>

Answer (score 3):

Install "Command Line Tools" from "Download Preferences" in Xcode 4.3 and above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider installing the new Apple Command Line Developer Tools package to get a full setup including manpages.  I commented on the issue and provided the linky [here](http://staticimport.blogspot.com/2012/02/mac-os-x-lion-command-line-developer.html).