# pip install readline on Mac OS X (10.7.3) fails

Tags: xcode4, osx-lion, python-2.7, pip, readline

When building the c extensions of readline when installing readline via `pip install readline`, I get an error message as follows:-

```
Beginning configuration for readline-6.2 for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0



checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes

checking for gcc... gcc

checking for C compiler default output file name...

configure: error: in `/Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/myproj/build/readline/rl/readline-lib':

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details.





============ Building the readline library ============





============ Building the readline extension module ============



running install

running build

running build_ext

building 'readline' extension

Compiling with an SDK that doesn't seem to exist: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
```

Searching for the location of MacOSX10.7.sdk on my system reveals:-

```
calvin$ sudo find / -name "MacOSX10.7.sdk"
Password:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
```

Which is not where the readline compilation is expecting.

Is there a bug with how pip locates the MacOSX10.7.sdk?

How do I resolve this without resorting to copying MacOSX10.7 into the `/Developer/SDKs` directory?

**CLARIFICATION**

This is how I temporarily solve my problem.

```
calvin$ sudo mkdir -p /Developer/SDKs/
Password:

calvin$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk

calvin$ pip install readline
```

But I am not too sure this is the "appropriate" way to solve it as there might be some inherent problems either from how pip is supposed to locate my .sdk location or I am missing something in my system PATH. So any advice on how to resolve this the "appropriate" way would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question. As a point of note, I *do* have a `MacOSX10.7.sdk` folder in `/Developer/SDKs`, so perhaps it's your filesystem's state that's wrong.

The safest approach is probably to install XCode, but that's horribly expensive in terms of time. I would start by creating a soft link:

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk`

and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly how I resolved my problem.

So now I am wondering what I did wrong when installing Xcode... which shouldn't be the case since I am able to compile my iphone apps from Xcode without any problems...

Comment: Aha. It appears that is because I am using the latest version of Xcode, which has moved its MacOSX10.7.sdk location!  Reference link to https://trac.macports.org/ticket/33283 where other developers building libraries encountered the same problem and is seeking clarification with the Port maintainer to change/update the sdk location.

Comment: It will get fixed in the next releases of Python:  http://bugs.python.org/issue14499

Comment: Another way of achieving this is installing the command line tools of XCode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376042/mac-os-x-lion-has-no-developer-usr-folder